# Angular Material ngTemplateOutlet within mat-select Not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a tree structure of data and I want to populate `mat-options` by recursively traversing the tree. I thought it would be pretty easy to implement using `ngTemplateOutlet` but for some reason this breaks the `mat-select` binding. The mat-options show up and when you click them their status changes to 'active' but they otherwise are not bound to the `mat-select` object (e.g., clicking doesn't close the select box).

Is there a way to achieve the functionality I am looking for? Also, what principle causes the behavior I am seeing?

Here's a demo of what is happening: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvtq8h

And here's a copy of the html of the component:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option [value]="'a'">A</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'b'">B</mat-option>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="otherOptions"></ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


<ng-template #otherOptions>
    <mat-option [value]="'c'">Other</mat-option>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: did you mange to find a fix?

Comment: I did not. I don't remember what I did but I think I ended up flattening the tree into a list with some hack to make it appear like a tree.

Comment: will trade internet points for hack

Comment: I believe I just manually created the tree structure, adding spacing for child nodes and made it so that the child nodes would be shown/hidden based on the parent being clicked.